# Change color of title bar in Konsole terminal emulator

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, terminal-emulator, konsole

I'm using Konsole terminal emulator in Debian bullseye.
And with the default color setting, I think the active tab is not distinguishable, so, I want to change the color of active tab to other color like red.(like terminator)
I've added "user-defined stylesheet" like below.

```
QTabBar,
QTabBar::tab
{
    font-family: "Noto Sans";
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 16px;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 0px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid palette(dark);
    background-color: palette(dark);
    color: palette(text);
}

QTabBar::tab:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

QTabBar::tab:selected
{
    color: yellow;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-top: 3px solid red;
}
```

But it's still showing default grey colored tab bar.
Anything I missed to configure? Or some other configuration is overwriting this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's for a detail of the terminal emulator (see [this](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/konsole/konsole/tabbarstylsheet.html)), rather than for *window decorations* (some window manager ***may*** support this).

Answer (score 0):

I've got some clues it might not be 100% answer for my original.
When I added below code at the front of the css file, konsole finally started to response.

```
QWidget, QTabWidget::pane, QTabWidget::tab-bar {
    background-color: #444444; /* Background colour of choice here */
}
```

But actually I've set the "selected" tab color as `red`.
It's showing a kind of weird dark grey color.
Without the above code, it never changed. But it's at least showing something(not the intended way though.. :p).

Will keep digging if any chance.

Comment: Can you please post the full path and filename of the CSS file?

Comment: Sorry, have just seen this. you can edit .css file anywhere and add it under [TabBar] in konsolrc file under .config dir. e.g.,
TabBarUserStyleSheetFile=file:///home/ryan/Documents/kosole.userdefined.css